# location of object word when the verb comes first

Tags: word-order, grammar-identification

We can say:
'When I go to Berlin, everyone will invite me'

> Wenn ich nach Berlin komme, wird mich jeder einladen.

Can we also say?:

> Wenn ich nach Berlin komme, wird jeder mich einladen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both variants are possible. As often in German, word order is a matter of emphasis.

> …, wird mich jeder einladen. *(Standard, no special emphasis.)*
>
> …, wird **jeder** mich einladen. *(Reversed, emphasis on **jeder**.)*

Comment: Danke, das ist klar.

Comment: Please be aware that this applies to pronouns specifically. A sentence with normal nouns cannot be reordered without sounding slightly to majorly weird: "...wird den Minister der Ausschuss einbestellen" is far less acceptable than the canonical word order.