# Komm mit zum Surfen oder Komm zum Surfen mit?

Tags: verb, word-order

> 1. Komm mit zum Surfen!
> 2. Komm zum Surfen mit!

I figured out that we either write them in the Mittelfeld or the Nachfeld, and the Particle stays in the Rechte Klammer. Are these two just options you have, or is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 5):

Both works. It's a matter of what you want to put emphasis on:

This is the more usual word order with a slight emphasis on "mitkommen":

> Komm mit zum Surfen

Put emphasis on "Surfen":

> Komm zum Surfen mit

Related questions with similar examples concerning word order:

- [location of object word when the verb comes first](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48772/location-of-object-word-when-the-verb-comes-first/48775#48775)
- [Meaning of word order inversion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/meaning-of-word-order-inversion)
- [Is the sentence "Er trifft seine Mitbewohner im Café jeden Tag" wrong ? Why?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71946/is-the-sentence-er-trifft-seine-mitbewohner-im-caf%c3%a9-jeden-tag-wrong-why)

Generally the tag "[word-order](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order)" will give you more.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use square brackets [ ] to delimitate the *Mittelfeld*. In the first example, *zum Surfen* is not necessarily positioned in the *Nachfeld*. This can be shown by adding a verb that clearly marks the *rechte Klammer*.

> 1) Komm [ mit zum Surfen ] !
> 2) Willst [ du mit zum Surfen ] kommen ?

The conclusion is that *mit* isn't always part of a particle verb; it can stand on its own.
This type of *mit* has its own [dictionary entry](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mit#2) with further examples. Free *mit* allows  frontings that are not available with particle verbs.

> 3) Mit zum Surfen komme ich aber nicht jeden Tag.
> 4) *Hinzu als Belastung kam das andauernde griechische Schuldendrama.
> 5) Als Belastung hinzu kam das andauernde griechische Schuldendrama. (*Zeit*, 10.3.2015, via [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r))

A parallel contrast can be observed between 2) and 6); unlike the free *mit* of 2), the particle in 6) cannot be moved to the left.

> 6) *da das andauernde griechische Schuldendrama hinzu als Belastung kam
> 7) da das andauernde griechische Schuldendrama als Belastung hinzukam

As far as preference is concerned, I find 8) more natural than 9). Even for speakers that don't share this judgement, 9) is the more peculiar construction as it isn't always available.

> 8) Komm mit zum Surfen!
> 9) Komm zum Surfen mit!
> 10) Ich bin gerne mit dabei.
> 11) *Ich bin gerne dabei mit.

An example with a particle verb and *Ausklammerung* (movement into the *Nachfeld*) would be:

> 12) Hast [ du eigentlich während der Vorlesung ] mitgeschrieben?
> 13) Hast [ du eigentlich  ] mitgeschrieben während der Vorlesung?

Comment: Would it be 10) Ich bin [gerne mit dabei] ? 
Thanks for the answer and examples.

Comment: I assume the question is whether *dabei* is part of the *Mittelfeld* or the *rechte Klammer*? For me, that's a matter of definition; one would probably have to think about how to analyse examples such as *wenn ich hätte dabei sein können*, *wenn ich hätte dort sein können*, etc. See [Oberfeld](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/2106).